# Which modes support local multiplayer and how to activate?

Tags: ps4, fifa-19

I am absolutely new to FIFA and it is my first multiplayer title for PS4.

I want to play local multiplayer but I don't know how to start it or get there.

I started a career and saw the screen where I can choose the side for each controller - I only see one controller there. I can switch using the 2nd by pressing its PS button but how to play with 2 players?

So did I something wrong or should I choose another mode?

Comment: u are absolutely right! this it is - thanks (make it an answer an i'll accept)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a different "account" for each controller. You can use either a guest account or simply create a new local account for frequent guests (like good friends or family members). Local accounts are "offline" accounts and not tied to a PSN account and only work on that specific console.

Comment: thanks for additional hint to create account for family